# Losing connection during continuous integration

Tags: jenkins, ssh, continuous-integration, digital-ocean, connection-timeout

I'm using DigitalOcean droplets for continuous integration.

Every time someone pushes something on our Github repository, a droplet is created. Then Jenkins (on a separated droplet) connects through ssh to the newly created droplet and launch a shell script that will build and test the project.

Github changes -> Jenkins (on droplet A) -> Build/tests (on new droplet X)

Github changes -> Jenkins (on droplet A) -> Build/tests (on new droplet Y)

Github changes -> Jenkins (on droplet A) -> Build/tests (on new droplet Z)

The problem is that randomly, the newly created droplet is losing connection to whatever it tried to connect to during the build. For example, 2/10 droplets with the same content would fail during a "git pull" command with this message :

`"ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out"`

or

`"[ComposerDownloaderTransportException] The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/symfony/zipball/d3646cc6875c214d211001e0673ec9e91b5f2da7" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out "`

There are no iptables rules and UFW is not enabled on those droplets. What could randomly block the connection to those services ?

Any suggestions ?

**[EDIT]**

To clarify

- It happened randomly during the build, a first 'git clone' command could succeed but another 'git clone' could failed 2 minutes after.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same kind of issues with my git repos. I created a script to try maximum 5 times if any git command fails.

Below is my script git_retry.
Example:

```
git_retry clone <clone_url>
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAX_RETRY_COUNTER=5
RETRY_SLEEP=10

try_number=0

while ! git $@
do
  if try_number=`expr $try_number + 1` && [ "$try_number" -lt $MAX_RETRY_COUNTER ];
  then
    echo "Warning: Issue during git operation. Try $try_number. Retrying in $RETRY_SLEEP seconds..."
    sleep $RETRY_SLEEP
    echo
  else
    echo "Error: Issue during git operation. Try $try_number..."
    echo
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I already did something similar and it works well for command that I call manually. The problem remains unfortunately because I don't call github by myself or in a shell-script. For example sometimes it happens during a "composer install" in a Symfony2 project but I cannot encapsulate this command in a retry loop process.